# Recurring tax payment puzzle

Tags: statistics

I came upon a puzzle where a farmer has to pay taxes to the kingdom in a recurring manner. The puzzle is as follows -

In a kingdom whenever a farmer sells his crops he has to pay 30% taxes on his income. Let's say farmer A has sold crops and earned 10000 coins but he forgot to pay the tax and spent all the 10000 coins. Now the officials of the kingdom remind him of the taxes so he sells crops worth 3000 more to settle his taxes. But then he has earned 3000 now and have to pay tax on them worth 900 coins. So he goes out and sells crops worth 900 but now he has to pay a tax of 270 on the 900 and the chain goes on...

Is there any mathematical formula or equation that could tell the farmer how many times he has to repeat this till his tax becomes zero or almost zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply equating the values as below but the series you have laid out is a geometric series and it does have a formula.

Simple equation: $x \times 0.3 + 3000 = x \, $, where $x$ is the value of crop he needs to cut and sell.

This gives you value of $x = \frac{30000}{7}$.

Now using the geometric series -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

He cuts just enough crop (valued at C) to pay taxes on $10000$ and on the crop he cut.

$C = 3000 + 3000 \times 0.3 + 3000 \times 0.3^2 + 3000 \times 0.3^3 + ...$

$C = 3000 + 3000 \times (0.3 + 0.3^2 + 0.3^3 + ...)$

Value for such geometric series for infinite terms is given by $s = \frac{a}{1-r} = \frac{0.3}{1-0.3} = \frac{3}{7}$

$a = 0.3$ is the first term. $r = 0.3$ is the common ratio.

So, $C = 3000 + 3000 \times \frac{3}{7} = \frac{30000}{7}$

Now he pays a tax of $\frac{9000}{7}$ on this. The remaining money with him is $3000$ which he pays in arrears.